# Unity3d - Two input buttons at once - delay in event triggering

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm making a game for two players. They both have a button that they can press to charge a meter, and then release to perform an action depending on how long they charged the meter.

I'm using left shift and right shift as the two player buttons.

The problem is, that if they are both charging at the same time, when one of them releases the button, the `Input.GetButtonUp` event is not fired until like half a second later.
If only one player is charging, then the event is triggered immediately when he releases.

Any ideas why and how to solve it?
It happened on two different PCs.

Edit: some code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObjectScript : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (isButtonDown(i))        // button first pressed
                buttonDown(i);
            if (isButtonUp(i))          // button released
                buttonUp(i);
            if (isButtonPressed(i))     // while button held pressed
                buttonIsPressed(i);
        }
    }

    // checks whether button has just been pressed down for given player
    private bool isButtonDown(int player) {
        return Input.GetButtonDown(getPlayerKeyName(player));
    }

    // checks whether button is held pressed down for given player
    private bool isButtonPressed(int player) {
        return Input.GetButton(getPlayerKeyName(player));
    }

    // checks whether has just been released for given player
    private bool isButtonUp(int player) {
        return Input.GetButtonUp(getPlayerKeyName(player));
    }

    // get the name of the key per player
    private string getPlayerKeyName(int player) {
        return "Player" + (player+1).ToString() + "Key";
    }

    // when button is first pressed
    private void buttonDown(int player) {
        Debug.Log("Button pressed: " + player.ToString());
    }


    // while button is pressed
    private void buttonIsPressed(int player) {
    }

    // when button is first released
    private void buttonUp(int player) {
        Debug.Log("Button released: " + player.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code or a scaled down example.

Comment: Added. very simple, check for keys pressed by two players, and log when they are pressed/released. If both are held down, and one releases, it takes half a second to a second until the event registers and is logged.

Comment: How do you register the button presses exactly? Have you tried using `Input.GetButton`?

Comment: The problem is only with the button release. I tried using it directly and not within methods.